# WebServiceHost returning 405 not allowed on GET in .NET4.0

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

This simple WebserviceHost works when I compile it for .NET3.5 but not in 4.0
I access it from my browser with the URL http:// mycomputer:8081/SVC/HelloWorld

The 3.5 version returns the"Hello World! @ <time>" string, but the 4.0 version returns - 405 Not Allowed.

Does anyone know why?

I'm using .net4.0 on a Win7 SP1 64bit machine

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "HelloWorld")]
    string HellWorld();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string HellWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World! @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
    }
}

public class MyClass
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string myComputer = "myComputer";
        string mySvcUri = "http://" + myComputer + ":8081/SVC";
        Uri[] baseAddresses = new Uri[] { new Uri(mySvcUri) };

        WebServiceHost hostVisits = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddresses);
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        hostVisits.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, "MyService");

        hostVisits.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service host started, press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Nothing is written to the eventlog.

Comment: Interestingly it works on a virtual machine with windowsXP/.net4.0 that I also use for development..

Answer (score 1):

Just remove these two lines. It will work.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
hostVisits.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, "MyService");
```

Comment: It does. Do you know why? My code above was extracted from a project written by someone else that I am maintaining so I don't exactly know why this does not work...